Google photos deleted all the pictures from my device. And yes wasn´t me
So, I´m really pissed :)
Last month my phone started to die, so before it died completely I switched to another I have. I have google cloud active for sms, photos contacts, whats app etc.. For years I monthly transfer photos and videos for free spacing and within the 15GB limit. (Backup)
All went well with the migration process in phones, contacts, sms, calls, whatsapp etc..
But when I looked at  my google photos app in new and older phone after maybe 5 minutes from all the syncs had finished, What was my amazement when I got no photos in the google photos. Try web google photos and nothing too. In worst case scenario should be in recycle bin for 60 days.
I´m not a newbie in this things and work in IT. but this is scary.
I contacted google and they are sending stupid responses.
I'm telling them to see the historic commands, that they should have to see i´m not covering some stupid mistakes. I have a print too that shows that for some hours the drive got the space of photos with storage used, but not showing to me. Now is permanently empty.
I tried used some programs like recuva etc and only found whats app old photos.
My last chance is if the cache of my old phone that i can see is accessible, have something like 1,25 gb. Don´t know if google saves his photos there. The folder on android -> com.google.android.apps.photos don't have nothing too.
Any tips?
Be aware Guys
